# What's wrong with my function for making async calls to an endpoint and collecting responses?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

I have a use-case where I need to hit an endpoint to fetch some data. The endpoint takes start-date-time and end-date-time as params and has a limitation that the duration between them can only be <= 24hrs. So if I want to fetch data for a duration of more than 24hrs, I need to make individual api calls passing the divided intervals as params.

I have come-up with below code using @Async annotation and it is fetching the data as required. But I am suspecting this is not executing/making the calls concurrently as the response time is increasing hugely as the no. of intervals increase.

```
public List<Response> makeAsyncCalls(Collection<Pair<LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime>> intervals) {

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    List<CompletableFuture<Response>> responses = new ArrayList<>();
    intervals.stream()
        .map((Pair<LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime> interval) -> Pair.of(interval.getLeft().format(formatter),
            interval.getRight().format(formatter))).forEach(timeInterval -> {
            try {
                responses.add(
                    fetchDataFromEndPoint(timeInterval));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //throw some custom exception here
            }
        });
    CompletableFuture<Void> completedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(responses.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
    if (completedFuture.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
        //throw exception
    }
    return responses.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(toList());
}

@Async
public CompletableFuture<Response> fetchDataFromEndPoint(Pair<String, String> interval)
            throws Exception {
            //Here service class has the webTarget that makes the call to the endpoint.
            Response response = service.getResponse(interval.getLeft(), interval.getRight());
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response);
        }
```

Approx response times:

| Interval size | Response time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7~9 seconds |
| 3 | 22~23 seconds |
| 5 | ~30 seconds |

Comment: So when you say “it is working fine” you mean it does exactly what it would do without the `@Async` annotation?

Comment: @Holger Yes. As per my understanding, the response time should be the max time of all the response times of each call. But that doesn't seem to be the case here

Comment: Try changing @Async mechanism to Worker threads using CompletableFuture.supplyAsync().

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are actually blocking on service.getResponse(interval.getLeft(), interval.getRight()). Therefore, you are not making concurrent calls to the endpoint.

Try changing @Async mechanism to Worker threads using CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()

```
public CompletableFuture<String> fetchDataFromEndPoint(Pair<String,String> interval){
    CompletableFuture<String> futureResponse =
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getResponse(interval.getLeft(), interval.getRight())); 

    return futureResponse;
}
```

Comment: So there would be no need for the `@Async` annotation ?

Comment: Keep the async annotation! My point was to move the service.getResponse call to another thread... another idea would be to implement getResponse as an async function as well.